# how to install c++ fastcgi development library?

Tags: 12.10, package-management, c++, cgi

I can't seem to find anything on this.

I know `apt-get install`, but I don't know the name of the package for the standard c++ fastcgi development library.

What is it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you will have to install boost first

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
```

I am not aware of a fastcgi c++ package in ubuntu so...

download the library from [nongnu.org](http://www.nongnu.org/fastcgipp/)

```
wget http://download.savannah.nongnu.org/releases/fastcgipp/fastcgi++-2.1.tar.bz2
```

extract archive

```
tar -xvf fastcgi++-2.1.tar.bz2
```

build

```
cd fastcgi++-2.1
./configure
make
make check
sudo make install
```

Comment: oh sweet!  i didn't know fastcgi++ had sessions integrated.  thank you!

Comment: @JoeCoderGuy You're welcome. Happy coding.

Answer (score 4):

This command worked for Ubuntu 14.04 (but I'm not sure about previous Ubuntu releases):

```
sudo apt-get install libfcgi-dev
```